# Should we be asking questions regarding Open Source Salesforce Software?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Regarding [System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Class.UserAccessDetailsController.getObjectLabels: line 290, column 1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/107617), I discovered that we're using the exact same code, which is from [forcedotcom/user-access-visualization](https://github.com/forcedotcom/user-access-visualization), which actually tests fine in my Sandbox and Production, but generates a System.NullPointerException *only during deployment*. I'm thinking about raising an issue, but I wanted to know if this is really question really is "off topic" (the close reason given, even though it's actual Apex Code, but given to us by Salesforce), or if it should have been "unclear what you're asking" (because that's a much more valid close reason as written), or if it could even be salvaged as a legit question, being that this is indeed a rather unusual condition.

Comment: imo it shouldn't be off-topic but more as "unclear what you're asking"  / "please put more effort into your question and explain what is not clear for you".

Comment: I have to say I'm glad you posted this. I think it's unfortunate that many valid questions are closed because we don't give sufficient time for people to respond to feedback and clarify. I also see questions being closed as duplicates which frequently have better answers than the original questions they presumably duplicated. That seems unwise and I've been meaning to post on that, but thought I'd tag the comment onto your post here.

Comment: I think it got flagged as off topic because it just looks like a code dump with no effort made towards a solution. It doesn't help that the top part about which line is 290 is merged into the same formatting block.

Comment: Guys if you feel that questions are closed too fast by the community for a incorrect reason or with too few comments-> feel free to flag 'm so that moderators can take a look. I regularly post-explain why questions were-and-remain closed, or re-open them with some edits.

Comment: I think sfdcfox is asking whether we should be "entertaining at all" questions about Open Source SFDC software from forcedotcom https://github.com/forcedotcom , or whether the questioner should post an Issue to the git repo (and the OP should be closed by the community)

Comment: @crop1645 Exactly. Bonus points because whoever maintains this repo clearly hasn't even noticed the pull request in the past... week. It's been seven calendar days without even an acknowledgement. Plus, nobody's emailed me, commented on the pull request, or anything else. I realize that there are people with real jobs out there, but I also realize there's real people with real jobs that depend on code like this. Also, it's been five days from premier support with a bug I posted in junction with this that outlines the bug in particular.

Comment: but surely premier support has asked you if you've granted them login access at least three times so that is progress, no? :-)